# Google Login with Oath2 - PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am following the code in this page: http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/

My **google_login.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'gp_config.php';
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
//Get user profile data from google

$gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
$oauth_provider = 'google';
$oauth_id = $gpUserProfile['id'];
$username = $gpUserProfile['given_name'] . $gpUserProfile['family_name'];
$email = $gpUserProfile['email'];
$picture = $gpUserProfile['picture'];

//Check whether user data already exists in database
$user_exist = get_user_by_provider_and_id($oauth_provider, $oauth_id);

//Update user data if already exists
if ($user_exist) {
    update_user_info($username, $email, $picture, $oauth_provider, $oauth_id);
}

// Insert new  user data if not already exists
if (!$user_exist) {
    create_new_user($username, $email, $picture, $oauth_provider, $oauth_id);
}

// Session
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: ../html/pause.html');
}
```

My **gp_config.php**:

```
<?php

// Require libraries
require_once ('../google-plus-api-client-master/src/Google_Client.php');
require_once ('../google-plus-api-client-master/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php');

/*
* Configuration and setup Google API
*/
session_start();
$clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
//$redirectURL = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$redirectURL = 'http://localhost/project/php/google_login.php';
$simple_api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

//Call Google API
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Login to TravNow.com');
$gClient->setClientId($clientId);
$gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey($simple_api_key);
$gClient->setAccessType('online');
$gClient>setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);
?>
```

In my **index.php** There is a **Google Logi**n button to load **google_login.php**

The code above does not work at all, it just shows me a blank page

But if I replace this block of code in **google_login.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

to:

```
$gClient->authenticate();
$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
```

then my code will work.

In the first version, it seems like Google does not send me any *code* so my **google_login.php** cannot GET it.

Is there much of a difference? And are there any problems with my solution?

Comment: few important notes: 1. ['code'] is sent only once after the first user's consent to use your app 2. The access token has a very short life (3600 seconds = 1 hour), you must save the user’s refresh token which has infinite lifetime. It's also being send once, get it with `$gClient->authenticate($_GET[‘code’])`

Comment: `header('Location: '` assumes immediate script ending but there is no `exit;` after the 7th line

Comment: Ok... and how is this related? What's the problem you are facing now?

Comment: My question is why the first version does not work while the second one works?